# Multiple Filters on useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
if (status || group) {
  setFilteredProjects(
    projects.filter((project) => {
      if (group !== "" && status !== "") {
        return (
          project.status === status && project.workgroup.name === group
        );
      } else {
        return (
          project.status === status || project.workgroup.name === group
        );
      }
    })
  );
} else {
  setFilteredProjects(projects);
}
}, [status, group, projects]);
```

This fragment of code is currently working, but I feel there is a far more elegant way of writing it.

Comment: Looks pretty reasonable to me. You could add a shortcut or two, like just checking `if (group && status)` and returning early with `setFilteredProjects(projects);` instead of nesting indentation.

Comment: You are right, to be honest I think what really bothers me in this fragment is the double return within that if else selection.

Comment: Could save matches in a variable first and use the conditional operator. Still pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
const filteredProjects = projects.filter((project) => {
      return group !== "" && status !== "" 
          ? project.status === status && project.workgroup.name === group
          : project.status === status || project.workgroup.name === group;
    });

setFilteredProjects(filteredProjects);
```